# Difference between executing PHP code from the commandline and from the HTTP side

Tags: php

What is the difference between executing PHP code from the command line and from HTTP?

Do they use the same executable such as (php.exe or php-cgi.exe ([Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) or [IIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services)))? Do the results differ when they are executing from the command line or HTTP?

Answer (score 7):

#### No HTML markup in errors

This is a *php.ini* setting ([html_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.html-errors)), but this defaults to off in the CLI version.

#### Logging to standard error

Usually errors are logged to the web server's *error.log* file, but in the CLI version, errors are written to [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)).

This is also available as a *php.ini* setting ([error_log](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log)).

#### php.ini

The *php.ini* file that is used for the CLI version can be a **different file**. Which can lead to some nasty bugs (curl suddenly not available, etc.).

#### Different executables

It's possible to install multiple version of PHP ([PHP 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Release_history) alongside PHP 7). Use `which php` to determine which version you're using.

#### Everything is shown as text

[var_dump()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) is readable without a `<pre>`. There isn't any
difference between `header('Hello');` and `echo('Hello');`.

Answer (score 2):

Whether PHP is invoked via a web server module or CLI, the same binary base is used (but can sometimes be configured to use different ini's which can affect the script). Its environment will also be different so environment variables will not be exact.

PHP is also aware that it's been invoked differently and will tailor its output to suit that (i.e., `phpinfo();` output will be formatted differently when called via CLI).

Comment: Or they use a different binary. Most implementations I came across had an entirely different version for cli & apache module, sometimes not even the same version....

Comment: @Wrikken. That must have been done purposefully by the admin for some reason. Either way, I've referred to it now as `binary base`

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is argument passing: running from the CLI, you don't have [$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), [$_POST](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php), $_SESSION, etc.; so arguments have to be passed as command line parameters and accessed using if *$_SERVER['argc']* and *$_SERVER['argv']*.

Watch out for the directory your code is running in and the include path; and make sure you know what *php.ini* file you've loaded.

When outputting, HTML markup doesn't render as markup, but displays as <h1>, etc.... watch out particularly for <br /> (PHP_EOL is extremely useful) and multiple spaces or tabs actually appear as multiple spaces or tabs rather than a single space.

Forget headers() and other HTTP-specific functions.

Answer (score 1):

When you are executing PHP code from the command line, your server, [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) or [IIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services), has no role to play.

You just use the PHP 4 or PHP 5 folder to execute your code. There may be differences with the execution as per the difference in libraries available and file *php.ini* settings in the two folders. When running from Apache, file *php.ini* within your *apache/bin* folder is used.

When from the command line, file *php.ini* from your *php5* or *php4* folder is used.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, everything is the same. The big differences are that the super globals might not be populated.

The best place to look at these would be on php.net,
*[Using PHP from the command line](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php)*

Answer (score 1):

Other than what already said, there will likely be differences in privileges as to what parts of the filesystem are accessible: PHP via a web server is run as the web server user, and PHP from the command line is run as yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Extending [Bob Fanger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016281/difference-between-executing-php-code-from-the-commandline-and-from-the-http-sid/3016824#3016824) a bit:

Running PHP files from the command line is quite trivial. You only have to keep in mind that there are some differences from running the file on a web server or on a servers CLI:

- No [cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) available
- No `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_SESSION` available
  But you can use `$argv` to get parameters passed as an argument to the command. The first value is always the file name.

  For example, taken this file:

  ```
  <?php
  var_dump($argv);
  ?>
  ```

called like this:

```
    user@ubuntu:$ /usr/bin/php /home/user/file.php foo bar
```

would give you this output:

```
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "file.php"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "foo"
      [2]=>
      string(3) "bar"
    }
```

- Full file paths from your servers root are required
  You will need to provide the full paths to your files (e.g., for `include()`, `require()`, `file_get_contents()`, ... ), even though they might be in the same folder.
- different user/permission settings.
  The files aren't getting executed by `www-data` user, but by the user you are logged in into your machine. This affects all your file's function calls that effect the machines file system, (e.g. `mkdir()`, `include()`, ... ), so you have to make sure to give appropriate permission to that user.

Comment: Adding to this useful compendulum of answers, `$_SERVER` variables are also unavailable to the script in CLI , such as `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` for accessing includes on a script.