# What is difference between PHP cli and PHP cgi?

Tags: php, cgi

I just found two executable files, `php-cgi.exe` and `php.exe` in the `bin` folder of the [WAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)#Variants) server on my laptop. I am learning PHP and could not figure out the difference. What is difference between them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between executing php from the commandline and from the Http Side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016281/difference-between-executing-php-from-the-commandline-and-from-the-http-side)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

PHP CLI is the command-line interface for PHP (e.g. for creating standalone applications)
PHP CGI is the common gateway interface for PHP (e.g. for web applications)

Comment: and PHP is Php Hypertext Preprocessor. Is that really an answer?! I dont think so

Comment: I thought PHP was an acronym for Personal Home Page. None of this recursive TLA fancy stuff :P

Answer (score 64):

From http://www.php-cli.com/php-cli-cgi.shtml

These are the most important differences between CLI and CGI:

- Unlike the CGI SAPI, CLI writes no headers to the output by default
- There are some php.ini directives which are overridden by the CLI
  SAPI because they do not make sense in shell environments:

  - **html_errors**: CLI default is FALSE
  - **implicit_flush**: CLI default is TRUE
  - **max_execution_time**: CLI default is 0 (unlimited)
  - **register_argc_argv**: CLI default is TRUE
- You can have command line arguments with your script! Variable
  "$argc" provides you with a number of arguments passed to the
  application. And array "$argv" gives you an array of the actual
  arguments
- There are 3 new constant defined for the shell environment:
  STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR. All of them are file handlers for
  correspondent shell devices. For example STDIN is the handler for
  fopen('php://stdin', 'r') . So, you can read a line from STDIN like
  this: $strLine = trim(fgets(STDIN));. STDIN is already defined for
  you by PHP CLI!
- PHP CLI does not change the current directory to the directory of the
  executed script. The current directory for the script would be the
  directory where your type PHP CLI command.
- There are number of USEFUL options available for PHP CLI. Which will
  allow you to get some valuable information about you php setup, your
  php script or run it in different modes.
- In PHP 5 there were some changes in CLI and CGI filenames. In PHP 5,
  the CGI version was renamed to php-cgi.exe (previously php.exe) and
  the CLI version now sits in the main directory (previously
  cli/php.exe).
- In PHP 5 it was also introduced a new mode: php-win.exe. This is
  equal to the CLI version, except that php-win doesn't output anything
  and thus provides no console (no "dos box" appears on the screen).
  This behaviour is similar to PHP GTK.

Comment: Hi there, do you know if it has some timeout? I mean if a need to run a script that takes too long to run. Is it a good option to run on CLI?

Comment: Yes, for sure. In CLI max_execution_time: default is 0 (unlimited).

Answer (score 61):

*This might give you a broader understanding of their difference:*

**CGI:** (common gateway interface) It is a specification "protocol" for transferring information between a Web server and a CGI program.

A CGI program is any program designed to accept and return data that conforms to the CGI specification.

Basically it's a way to run a server side script (PHP, Perl, Python,...) when a HTTP request comes.

CGI is very slow in comparison to other alternatives.

---

**FastCGI:** is a better CGI.

Fast CGI is a different approach with much faster results.

It is a CGI with only a few extensions.

FastCGI implementation isn’t available anymore, in favor of the PHP-FPM.

---

**PHP-FPM:** (FastCGI Process Manager), it's a better FastCGI implementation than the old FastCGI.

It runs as a standalone FastCGI server.

In general it's a PHP interface for the web servers (Apache, Nginx..) to allows Web Server to interact with PHP.

Unlike the **PHP-CLI** which is a command line interface for PHP to allows Users to interact with PHP via terminal.

---

**mod_php:** an Apache module to run PHP.

It execute PHP scripts inside the Web Server directly as part of the web server without communicating with a CGI program.

---

**mod_SuPHP:** is similar to mod_php but can change the user/group that the process runs under.

Basically it address some problems of mod_php related to permissions.

Answer (score 18):

`php-cgi` is intended for a webserver. Among other things it handles HTTP headers for you.

The CLI version is intended to run on a command line (hence "Command Line Interface"). This one does not handle headers, or any other server-related things.

Answer (score 8):

CLI is for command line scripts, CGI is for web requests

Answer (score 8):

`php-cli` is meant for running PHP on the command line.  `php-cgi` does additional things for you, such as HTTP headers and certain security modifications.

Having said that, consider installing a FastCGI module and using [PHP's FastCGI interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php).  This should run PHP noticably faster than php-cgi.  I believe the standard Apache FastCGI module is [`mod_fcgid`](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/).

Answer (score 1):

A little excerpt from an article I am writing entitled ***Understanding PHP***...

`/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so`

The actual file name of the Apache-specific PHP Interpreter that is typically loaded into the modular Apache System, thus enabling it to interpret PHP scripts.

`/usr/bin/php`

A PHP Interpreter intended for stand-alone PHP applications invoked via the command line.  This interpreter helps to position PHP as a Web Server independent general-purpose programming or scripting language.

`/usr/bin/php-cgi`

A Common Gateway Interface PHP Interpreter intended for receiving PHP scripts via the agency of a Web Server.  This is the original implementation methodology of PHP, and it is mostly a legacy thing considering that other CGI approaches (such as FastCGI and php-fpm) offer better performance.  Therefore, php-cgi should only be used as a last resort, when no other better performing options are available.