# how to configure adminlte with yii2 basic?

Tags: php, linux, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm using yii2 basic application. what i want is i have to configure adminlte with yii2 basic. So that i have used this composer.

```
 composer require dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset "2.*"
```

while running this command in terminal i got the below errors. I don't know what it is.

```
Problem 1
- yiisoft/yii2 2.0.10 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- yiisoft/yii2 2.0.10 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- yiisoft/yii2 2.0.10 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 (locked at 2.0.10, required as ~2.0.5) -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.10].
To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
```

You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

```
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Should i install anything. I'm using linux (ubuntu) and php version is 5.6. Can anyone help to figure it out?

Comment: Mate, it says right there - you need to install mbstring. Do something like `sudo apt-get install php5.6-mbstring` or whatever works on your system.

Comment: I have installed it. But having the same issue.

Comment: So restart your server. And btw - you say you are using PHP5.6 but Composer detects PHP7.1 in CLI. Check your system config.

Comment: I have checked system configuration PHP Version 5.6.25-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1

Comment: In console? This is what `php -v` outputs?

Comment: PHP 7.1.0-5+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) ( NTS )

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php7.1-mbstring` And what is the point of CLI7.1 and CGI5.6?

Comment: i have installed this sudo apt-get install php7.1-mbstring

Comment: and what is  CLI7.1 and CGI5.6 . I didnt get u

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did not realise you are just starting the beautiful journey into the world of PHP. Please read the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/docs.php). As for your last question I believe you can find answer in [this Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315714/what-is-difference-between-php-cli-and-php-cgi)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composer error while installing Laravel: 'mbstring' is missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690561/composer-error-while-installing-laravel-mbstring-is-missing)

Answer (score -1):

First you need to install php mbstring package. Once it is installed and you run composer command, make sure you have added all dependent package in your composer.json otherwise you may have dependencies issues according to your installed packages.