# PHP Thread class not founded with PHP7

Tags: php, apache, pthreads, php-7.2

I am trying to enable `Thread` with PHP script. I have followed the following steps for enabling PHP thread.

Step 1:- Download and unzip pthread lib from [here](https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/3.1.6/)

Step 2:- Copy `php_pthreads.dll` and paste into the `php\php7.2.14\ext` and `php\php7.2.14\` folder.

Step 3:- and `pthreadVC2.dll` and paste into the `apache\apache2.4.37\bin`

Step 4:- Enable thread in php.ini which is located in a`pache\apache2.4.37\bin` and after updating its look like something below.

```
; Whether or not to enable the dl() function.  The dl() function does NOT work
; properly in multithreaded servers, such as IIS or Zeus, and is automatically
; disabled on them.
; http://php.net/enable-dl
enable_extension=On
extension=php_pthreads.dll
```

Step 5:- Enable thread in php.ini in which located at `\php\php7.2.14`

```
; Whether or not to enable the dl() function.  The dl() function does NOT work
; properly in multithreaded servers, such as IIS or Zeus, and is automatically
; disabled on them.
; http://php.net/enable-dl
enable_dl = On
extension=php_pthreads.dll
```

Step 6:- I have restarted wampp server with all services.

Still, I am getting the error as

```
 Fatal error: Class 'Thread' not found in {PHP file with location with line number}.
```

**Update**

I have changed DLL files and restarted a server as we discussed and redirect to a new error as below.

```
[24-Jan-2019 10:29:20 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  The apache2handler SAPI is not supported by pthreads in Unknown on line 0
[24-Jan-2019 10:29:20 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Unable to start pthreads module in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: It seems like you're using the extension for 7.0 and not 7.2. Check [this issue](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/issues/792) on their Github for a link to a version that should work for 7.2 (it's still set as version 3.1.6, but has -7.2 instead of -7.0).

Comment: @Cid i have included #!/usr/bin/php in my script.

Comment: My comment was stupid. Check @MagnusEriksson one, this will lead you to the right way

Comment: @Cid  checking for his comment

Comment: If you are using WAMPServer as you say, then `#!/usr/bin/php` will not be understood by Windows!

Comment: As @MagnusEriksson said it looks like you are using the wrong version of the extension. And there does not seem to be a version at least in that repo for PHP 7.2. So you will have to switch your PHP version down to a PHP7.0 version to be able to use `pthreads`

Comment: READ THE MANUAL [for pthreads](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php) It specifically states **Warning** _The pthreads extension cannot be used in a web server environment. Threading in PHP is therefore restricted to CLI-based applications only._

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have to change the dll file as suggested but apache does not allow to start my those scripts and I search about this error. This script can be run with PHP CLI only. is there any alternative to execute with apache server?

Comment: @RiggsFolly so it means pthread does not support with php7.2. Am i right?

Comment: Well the [github](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads) suggests it is supported (PHP CLI Only **not on  web server**) but I have to assume that nobody has bothered to compile it for PHP7.1 or PHP7.2 as there does not seem to be a DLL compiled for any version of PHP after PHP7.0

Comment: This bit if the file name `php_pthreads-3.1.6-**7.0**-ts-vc14-x86.zip` normally denoted the version of PHP that the code is compiled for

Comment: Please read the comments properly again. As stated, you were using the wrong version of the dll (and the github issue linked to a working one for PHP 7.2). Then it also states that it does not work on web servers, which includes Apache (which is a web server). So, even after upgrading the dll to the correct version, you still can't use it with Apache (or any other web server). It only works on PHP-scripts that are executed through the command line (like `cmd` etc).

Comment: @DhiralKaniya I suggest you to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315714/what-is-difference-between-php-cli-and-php-cgi)

Comment: @all :- Finally I figure out the way and able to execute a script with pthread via cli. Learn a lot as i am new for PHP. thanks, each and everyone for important resources and guidance.