# PHP memory limit not being respected by apache

Tags: php, memory

I have /etc/opt/remi/php80/php.ini

memory_limit = 2048M

when i do:  php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"

I get: 2048M

phpinfo() shows

```
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/opt/remi/php80/php.ini
memory_limit    128M    128M
```

what am i missing?

notes:

memory_limit does not exist in any other ini file in any folder/subfolder of this dir.

I have restarted apache numerous times.

Comment: Actually php in cli and in web are different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is difference between PHP cli and PHP cgi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315714/what-is-difference-between-php-cli-and-php-cgi)

Comment: not even remotely.  how do i get apache to respect the 2048M memory_limit?

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/a/1302286

Comment: Which distro ?  Modern ones use php-fpm , so you have to restart the service (php80-php-fpm), not apache.

Answer (score 1):

Memory limit is decoded into a signed 32 bit integer number of bytes so you may be overflowing. Why not set it to -1 which is unlimited. Also if you're running php-fcgi then you need to restart that service rather than Apache.

Comment: memory_limit of -1 is strongly discouraged on production environments since that allows PHP to eat all your resources and crash the server