# PHP - Reading in a large XML file from Amazon S3 in cron job causes process to run out of memory

Tags: php, linux, memory, amazon-s3, cron

We have a process that is set to run at 1am every day as a batch job to perform some calculations we need in order to send out notice of updates to our users.

We're getting this message where the kernel is killing the process every time:

Apr  8 01:06:51 martha kernel: [14697876.360797] Out of memory: Kill 
process 20803 (processDirector) score 347 or sacrifice child

The OS (Ubuntu) seems to be dumping the memory to disk. The contents of that dump are a large XML file that we're reading in from S3.

Strangely, if I just run the script as ./processDirector from the command line, then it does execute successfully.

The XML file we're grabbing is often around the 40-70MB mark. We're using the Amazon S3 SDK2 and this is the code we're using to grab the XML file:

```
$result = $s3->getObject(array(
    'Bucket' => 'updates-uk',
    'Key' => $key,
));

$body = $result->get('Body');
$body->rewind();
return $body->read($result['ContentLength']);
```

What I'm wondering is if this is a problem with cron's configuration that only allows a process to use a certain amount of memory.

I'm using the PHP SAX XML parser in an attempt to increase the speed and prevent the program from needing to build a full SimpleXML object or similar.

My two thoughts on how to solve this are:

1. Find out how to allow cron jobs to use more memory
2. Read the XML file in stages into a file, and have the SAX parser parse from a file rather than holding the full 40-670MB XML string in memory.

If anyone has any thoughts on how to solve this, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be just PHP limiting how much memory the script is allowed to use:

To increase memory usage the command [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) should help you.  Here is an article on using it to [increase memory limit](http://davidwalsh.name/increase-php-memory-limit-ini_set) for a php script.

Comment: that doesn't really explain why it works when directly run, but not when cron runs it though?

Comment: PHP CLI uses a different php ini file (see this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016281/difference-between-executing-php-from-the-commandline-and-from-the-http-side) which could explain the difference.

Comment: But since crontab just executes a CLI script then it should be the same php.ini for executing via cron, or via CLI. I'm going to try your suggestion though, and let you know if it works.

Comment: Hmm; that's a good point - at least if this is not the answer we can rule out PHP ini settings.  I can't imagine where memory limit for cron processes is set - if that's what the issue is.

Comment: I tried increasing the memeory with ini_set but we're still having problems.