# Is there a difference in php scripts as part of a cron job and website php?

Tags: php, apache, cron

I have a number of processes on a website that I have now found I need to run every day at midnight.  I am trying to set this up using a cron job but I'm confused as to how this works.

The question is:
Is there a difference in how the php process is to be run to how it would normally run on a website?  Is there a format it needs to meet, or code that can/can't be run in one situation compared to another? This doesn't relate to specific code I am working on.  This is for a job I have yet to write but I can't seem to find the answer to this question.

Comment: A possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016281/difference-between-executing-php-from-the-commandline-and-from-the-http-side

Comment: where did the other answer go?

Comment: of course there will be differences, your machine is different that server's! but in what degree those differences are playing any role? Each http requests relies on configuration and therefore differences are to be expected, yet the operation is the same, except the limitations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is actually a difference in most typical PHP set-ups.  Typically, for PHP run via Apache for a website/web service, you would have a totally separate installation of PHP that is being used, complete with it's own php.ini configuration. PHP would typically be run as the website's user (httpd, www-data, etc. depending on your OS version)

For scripts run through cron you are typically using PHP CLI which has a totally separate configuration.  CLI also typically would have significant differences with regards to what is available within the auto-populated superglobals (i.e. $_SERVER) and would typically not have the concept of sessions nor the ability to propagate a session. The PHP CLI would be run as whatever user is running it (or specified in the cron).  This could have implications when compared to running via Apache with regards to directory and file permissions.

There are also different behaviors within certain PHP functions, between the two, so clearly you should test your code specifically for running in CLI.

This link in PHP manual explains some additional differences:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.differences.php

Comment: why do you need a separate version of php to run it?

Comment: @AlanDoolan BEcause in the typical Apache/PHP configuration, there is no standalone PHP able to run from command line, you need to run it through Apache.  You could certainly write a cron script to use cURL or similar to call PHP via Apache if you don't want to mess with CLI.