# DateTime converts wrong when system time is 30 March

Tags: php, date

Assume system time is set to 2017-03-30. Then this code will convert the date wrong:

```
<?php
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-Y', '02-2017');
$converted = $dateTime->format('Y-m');
print_r($converted);
```

The value of `$converted` is

```
2017-03
```

<s>but only when run *from the browser*. Run from command line, it gives the correct result `2017-02`.</s>

Anyone knows why? February does not have 30 days, so that might be a reason, but still.

**Edit**: Changed format from 'Y-m-d' to 'Y-m'.

**Edit 2**: Added information about command line vs browser.

Comment: In my enviroment, `$converted` yields: `2017-02-02` (UTC-03:00)

Comment: @RagenDazs OK, so it can be a setting somewhere, then. Thank you.

Comment: As stated in my answer and comments. Please can you clarify if adding a day value to your `$dateTime` construct negates the problem.

Comment: The rules used by [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to parse various date & time formats and the values it uses to fill missing components are explained in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php). In your specific case, `02-2017` is converted to "February 2017" using the current day of month (`30`) for the missing day of month. I.e. 30 February 2017 that is then normalized to 2 March 2017.

Comment: **[This topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016281/difference-between-executing-php-from-the-commandline-and-from-the-http-side)** should also be able to advise you of your differences because of CLI and browser based PHP

Comment: @RagenDazs because today is **2**nd of May. The poster specifies in the question that the "errant" behaviour happens when the system date is `2017-03-30`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rules used by [`DateTime::__construct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php), [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to parse various date & time formats and the values it uses to fill missing components are explained in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

When it parses an incomplete date, it uses the values from the current date and time for the missing components.

In your specific case, `02-2017` is converted to "February 2017" using the current day of month (`30`) for the missing day of month. I.e. 30 February 2017 that is then normalized to 2 March 2017.

You can tell [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to initialize all the components to the Unix epoch (instead of the current date & time) by placing an exclamation mark (`!`) in the format string:

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m-Y', '02-2017');
print_r($dateTime);
```

It outputs:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2017-02-01 00:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
```

Comment: Mention of the values it uses to fill missing components seems only to appear in the documentation against `!` in the list of format characters.  Easily missed and entirely unintuitive.

Answer (score 3):

What you have here is *over-run*. The process goes like this:

- 1) You give the `dateTime` object a formatted date, but without a day.
- 2) The dateTime object then can not use `null` days so instead uses todays date.
- 3) You state in your question that todays date is `2017-03-30` therefore to apply this to the given date value of `02-2017` would make:

  > 30-02-2017
- 4) This is obviously not valid so the `dateTime` object *over-runs* this value and turns it into `02-03-2017`.

You reqest an output format of `Year - Month` which gives you `2017-03`.

### Solution:

Always set a day value in your dates.

Comment: Actually, I would give @Ragen above right - if I put the snippet in its own file, it works as expected; in my software, it gives the wrong result. Question is which setting is affecting this.

Comment: Well you havn't said anything about this in your question. You need to outline (edit) the question and show what the differences between the two systems are, what the differences in output are on the two systems and take it from there. It's probably different versions of PHP or different setups of `dateTime` object or of your system time settings in your `php.ini` . My answer solves the issue you ask in your question, but you're now moving the goal posts as to what your question actually is asking `:-p`

Comment: From the _command line_ it gives the correct result, but not from the browser. Yeah, I will update the question.

Comment: And you should let us know if the issue disappears once you set a `day` value in your DateTime object. @OlleHärstedt

Comment: @Martin The issue will have disappeared after two days regardless of setting a `day` (though will be back at the end of the month if not fixed). Poor design from PHP, leading to error-prone software using it. Why not simply use `0` (or 1st of month) for missing fields, as other software (possibly including PHP in other situations) does? Do I now need to double-check my code where I haven't specified a time of day all the way down to picoseconds and beyond?  Maybe the Higgs Boson was only found due to this bug* in PHP, and doesn't actually exist after all.  *It is a bug, let's face it.