# PHP setlocale / strftime output differs between cli and web

Tags: php, setlocale, apache2-module

I know there are many questions about locale issues in PHP. But I can't find any similar question or answer. I need to output German month names on a website. German locale is installed. Here is the output of `locale -a`:

```
# locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
de_DE
de_DE.iso88591
de_DE.iso885915@euro
de_DE.utf8
de_DE@euro
deutsch
en_US.utf8
german
```

Now I just use a little test snippet:

```
<?php
echo setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf8')."\n";
echo strftime('%B %Y', strtotime('2022-03-20'))."\n";
```

Here is the correct output from executing it on the command line:

```
# php test.php
de_DE.utf8
März 2022
```

Now when I execute the same snippet on the same server with a web browser (file:///x.php) the correct locale will be loaded, but the output is in English:

```
de_DE.utf8
March 2022
```

Apache 2.4.38 is used as the web server. The php cli version is 7.2.34 and the php module on apache is `php7_module (shared)`. There must be a difference between the php cli and php apache modules, but I don't know the solution?

Thanks for help!

Comment: From [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70312801/1685196): try setting multiple names. Perhaps cli and module use different names for the same locale?

Comment: Thanks, yes i tried also `de_DE`, `de_DE.UTF-8`, `de_DE.iso88591`. Always the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was solved after disabling the Perl module with `a2dismod perl`. After this the website shows also the correct date format.

Comment: [Difference between executing PHP code from the commandline and from the HTTP side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016281/difference-between-executing-php-code-from-the-commandline-and-from-the-http-sid).    Check the difference for this: [php_ini_loaded_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php)

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I just compared the cli and apache php.ini version and I don't find a difference that causes this problem.